# How do I access hidden quests and complete the optional objectives?

Tags: dawn-of-heroes

Does anyone know how to get those darn hidden quests that have no clue in Dawn of Heroes? It seems like there are no FAQs for this yet.

Also, how is it possible to do some of the Optional Objectives. It seems impossible to kill all enemies in 2 turns when it takes 2 turns to kill at least one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the ones of killing the enemies in two turns when you have bigger level than them.

Take care if you are on the 4th barony because the campaign may reset to the second battle of that map if you travel to other maps (once you have the town I suggest you first unlock the 2 heroes before trying to complete that barony).

---

2010/10/01:

---

**Hidden Quests**

- The list below is completed. Some rewards may change (the ones that are not consumables)
- If you post this list somewhere else, show the source and the author
- Enjoy it :D

---

1. The Witch (1st Barony 1st quest) -> Giant Worm (Consumable)
2. Giant Worm -> Eagle quest (4th barony 1st quest) -> Dragon Egg (Consumable).
3. Dragon Egg -> Airborne (1st barony) -> Horned Amulet (Legendary Badge)

---

1. Red Key -> The Lesson (1st Barony) -> Iron Shackles (Consumable)
2. Iron Shackles -> Lair Raider (5th barony) -> Fire Rune (Consumable)
3. Fire Rune -> Ceremony (4th barony) -> Bony Amulet (Legendary Badge)

---

1. Brotherhood (2nd barony 1st quest) -> Coffee Machine (Consumable)
2. Coffee Machine -> Honey Honey (5th barony) -> No badge, no consumable

---

1. Safari (2nd barony) -> Prayer Book (Consumable)
2. Prayer Book -> Sage Miyagi (3rd barony) -> No badge, no consumable

---

1. Birthday Party (3rd barony 1st quest) -> Sword (main quest item)
2. Sword -> Unlocks a main quest

---

1. The Master (4th barony) -> Cuckoo Clock (Consumable)
2. Cuckoo Clock -> The Precious (2nd barony) -> No badge, no consumable

---

1. Gold Race (5th barony) -> Magical Barrel and Earth Ward (2 Consumables)
2. Magical Barrel -> Vegetarian (6th barony) -> Medal of Honor (Consumable)
3. Medal of Honor -> Treasure Hunt (3rd barony) -> Frosty Amulet (Legendary Badge)
4. Earth Ward -> Lies (3rd barony) -> No badge, no consumable

---

1. Dirty Job (5th barony) -> Silver Harp (Consumable)
2. Silver Harp -> The Siren (1st barony) -> Lorgnette (Consumable)
3. Lorgnette -> Tournament (4th barony) -> Fanged Amulet (Legendary Badge)

---

1. Water Skins (5th barony) -> Singing Fish (Consumable)
2. Singing Fish -> Giant Fish (1st barony) -> Ancestral Key (Consumable)
3. Ancestral Key -> The Chancellor (3rd barony) -> Snowy Amulet (Legendary Badge)

---

1. The Traitor (6th barony) -> Ancient Scroll (Consumable)
2. Ancient Scroll -> The Traitor (6th barony, battle for the treasure) -> Eyeless Skull (Consumable)
3. Eyeless Skull -> Diabolo 2 or Diabolo 3 (6th barony, both) -> One Eyed Skull (Consumable)
4. One Eyed Skull -> Diabolo 2 or 3 (The one still not done) -> Living Skull (Main Quest Item)

---

1. Catastrophe (6th barony) -> Rusty Spanner (Consumable)
2. Rusty Spanner -> Bomb Squad (4th barony) -> Robot Spider (Consumable)
3. Robot Spider -> Bug Infestation (2nd barony) -> Bloody Amulet (Legendary Badge)

---

1. The Door (6th barony) -> Big Cyan Key and Voodoo Doll (Consumable)
2. Voodoo Doll -> Ghost Town (2nd barony) -> Tin Foil Hat (Consumable)
3. Tin Foil Hat -> Impnapping (5th barony) -> Wicked Amulet (Legendary Badge)
4. Big Cyan Key -> Treasure (or Town if you unlock West spot) -> Ore Detector (Consumable)
5. Ore Detector -> Impbot (2nd barony) -> Shiny Ore (Consumable)
6. Shiny Ore -> Ashes To Ashes (1st barony) -> Fanged Amulet (Legendary Badge)

---

Tips:
I open the most of the treasures at level 25, but before killing the behemont. So I just get a tone of purple items and just 2 gold (non-badge) items. I think that the chance of gold items will rise if you open the chests after killing the behemont.
Once I discover how to kill it, I will make an update.

Comment: Is it a bug in the game?

Comment: Dont think so. They already tell you when you enter the realm, but ofc, not when you go out. So just make the 4th barony story-lane in a row, instead of trying to make hidden quests during it. Still Im not sure how it resets (roaming among maps), but its kinda anoying

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I'm just at the 5th barony and managed to get some of the secrets too.

Comment: It's hilarious how the first hint of how to do this is in the 6th barony. XD

Answer (score 1):

Hidden objectives: use the proper orange "potion" on the stage to complete them. There is sort of a relation between the orange item description and the stage description. I suck with names, but as far as I can recall, the "big worm" for example is used on scenario number four, on the stage where you are in a giant eagle...

Comment: Orange potion? Where's this orange potion?

Answer (score 1):

The orange potions are the specialty items like "Big Worm" that you get for completing the "Two Turn" special objectives. The "Big Worm" goes to the eagle. This is the first stage of the fourth Barony. There is also a Sage Book you get from the "Two Turn" turtle of the second barony. This goes to the Sage level in the Third Barony. I will post more as I figure them out.

Answer (score 1):

The orange potions are the specialty items like the "Big Worm" that you get for completing the "Two Turn" special objectives. Now, I use "Banish" to easily complete the "Two Turn" special objective fights, by put one on each character and using them on the toughest opponents first and slaughtering any weaker units. This game seems to have very little information any where online. Oh, here's another hint about using "Banish", which purchasable in town, you can use it earn money fast by knocking out the stronger 2 units in the hard level mercenary battles.